# How to use FIND_IN_SET using list of data

Tags: mysql

I have used `FIND_IN_SET` multiple times before but this case is a bit different.

Earlier I was searching a single value in the table like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name where find_in_set('1212121212', sku)
```

But now I have the list of SKUs which I want to search in the table. E.g

```
'3698520147','088586004490','868332000057','081308003405','088394000028','089541300893','0732511000148','009191711092','752830528161'
```

I have two columns in the table `SKU` LIKE 081308003405 and `SKU Variation`
In SKU column I am saving single value but in variation column I am saving the value in the comma-separated format LIKE `081308003405,088394000028,089541300893`

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name 
WHERE 1 
AND upc IN ('3698520147','088586004490','868332000057','081308003405','088394000028',
'089541300893','0732511000148','009191711092','752830528161')
```

I am using IN function to search UPC value now I want to search variation as well in the variation column. This is my concern is how to search using SKU list in variation column

For now, I have to check in the loop for UPC variation which is taking too much time. Below is the query

```
SELECT id FROM products 
WHERE 1 AND upcVariation AND FIND_IN_SET('88076164444',upc_variation) > 0
```

Comment: Well, I have found a way to do this thing in one query. I am using `OR ` clause to check all data in single query and it works faster than in for loop

Comment: Add your tables in SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ and also post your solution in answer, it would be helpful for others.

Comment: Is `sku` a single value?  Or is it a commalist?  If it is potentially a list, please make the column name plural (eg, `skus` or `sku_list`).  Else flip the arguments in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all consider to store the data in a normalized way. Here is a good read: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Now - Assumng the following schema and data:

```
create table products (
  id int auto_increment,
  upc varchar(50),
  upc_variation text,
  primary key (id),
  index (upc)
);
insert into products (upc, upc_variation) values
  ('01234', '01234,12345,23456'),
  ('56789', '45678,34567'),
  ('056789', '045678,034567');
```

We want to find products with variations `'12345'` and `'34567'`. The expected result is the 1st and the 2nd rows.

#### Normalized schema - many-to-many relation

Instead of storing the values in a comma separated list, create a new table, which maps product IDs with variations:

```
create table products_upc_variations (
  product_id int,
  upc_variation varchar(50),
  primary key (product_id, upc_variation),
  index  (upc_variation, product_id)
);
insert into products_upc_variations (product_id, upc_variation) values 
  (1, '01234'),
  (1, '12345'),
  (1, '23456'),
  (2, '45678'),
  (2, '34567'),
  (3, '045678'),
  (3, '034567');
```

The select query would be:

```
select distinct p.*
from products p
join products_upc_variations v on v.product_id = p.id
where v.upc_variation in ('12345', '34567');
```

As you see - With a normalized schema the problem can be solved with a quite basic query. And we can effectively use indices.

#### "Exploiting" a FULLTEXT INDEX

With a FULLTEXT INDEX on `(upc_variation)` you can use:

```
select p.*
from products p
where match (upc_variation) against ('12345 34567');
```

This looks quite "pretty" and is probably efficient. But though it works for this example, I wouldn't feel comfortable with this solution, because I can't say exactly, when it doesn't work.

#### Using JSON_OVERLAPS()

Since MySQL 8.0.17 you can use [JSON_OVERLAPS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-overlaps). You should either store the values as a JSON array, or convert the list to JSON "on the fly":

```
select p.*
from products p
where json_overlaps(
  '["12345","34567"]',
  concat('["', replace(upc_variation, ',', '","'), '"]')
);
```

No index can be used for this. But neither can for `FIND_IN_SET()`.

#### Using JSON_TABLE()

Since MySQL 8.0.4 you can use [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) to generate a normalized representation of the data "on the fly". Here again you would either store the data in a JSON array, or convert the list to JSON in the query:

```
select distinct p.*
from products p
join json_table(
  concat('["', replace(p.upc_variation, ',', '","'), '"]'),
  '$[*]' columns (upcv text path '$')
) v
where v.upcv in ('12345', '34567');
```

No index can be used here. And this is probably the slowest solution of all presented in this answer.

#### RLIKE / REGEXP

You can also use a [regular expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
select p.*
from products p
where p.upc_variation rlike '(^|,)(12345|34567)(,|$)'
```

See [demo of all queries on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=899ccd87b79ff943e55f6db37ca5dded)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE 1 AND ( FIND_IN_SET('3698520147', SKU) 
        OR UPC IN ('3698520147') )
```

Comment: I have already done the solution as I have mentioned below the question. By the way thanks for the answer

Comment: The syntax works, but performance is poor -- no index can be useful in your example -- it involves two different columns.  Hence, it will involve a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you, you can consider this solution:

1: Create a temporary table example here: [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bd7d1/1/0)

```
select
  tablename.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) sku_variation
from
  numbers inner join tablename
  on CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.sku_split)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.sku_split, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by id, n
```

2: Use the temporary table to filter. find in set with your data

Comment: How can use temporary table, without the stored procedure?

Comment: Just create a memory table using SQL query.

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl LIMIT 0;

Answer (score 0):

Performance considerations.  The main thing that matters for performance is whether some index can be used.  The complexity of the expression has only a minuscule impact on overall performance.

**Step 1** is to learn what can be optimized, and in what way:

```
Equal:        WHERE x = 1  -- can use index
IN/1:         WHERE x IN (1) -- Turned into the Equal case by Optimizer
IN/many:      WHERE x IN (22,33,44)  -- Usually worse than Equal and better than "range"
Easy OR:      WHERE (x = 22 OR x = 33) -- Turned into IN if possible
General OR:   WHERE (sku = 22 OR upc = 33) -- not sargable (cf UNION)
Easy LIKE:    WHERE x LIKE 'abc' -- turned into Equal
Range LIKE:   WHERE x LIKE 'abc%' -- equivalent to "range" test
Wild LIKE:    WHERE x LIKE '%abc%' -- not sargable
REGEXP:       WHERE x RLIKE 'aaa|bbb|ccc' -- not sargable
FIND_IN_SET:  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(x, '22,33,44')  -- not sargable, even for single item
JSON:         -- not sargable
FULLTEXT:     WHERE MATCH(x) AGAINST('aaa bbb ccc')  -- fast, but not equivalent
NOT:          WHERE NOT ((any of the above)) -- usually poor performance
```

"Sargable" -- able to use index.  Phrased differently "Hiding the column in a function call" prevents using an index.

FULLTEXT:  There are many restrictions: "word-oriented", min word size, stopwords, etc.  But it is very fast when it applies.  Note:  When used with outer tests, `MATCH` comes first (if possible), then further filtering will be done without the benefit of indexes, but on a smaller set of rows.

Even when an expression "can" use an index, it "may not".  Whether a `WHERE` clause makes good use of an index is a much longer discussion than can be put here.

**Step 2**  Learn how to build *composite* indexes when you have multiple tests (`WHERE ... AND ...`):

When constructing a composite (multi-column) index, include columns in this order:

1. 'Equal' -- any number of such columns.
2. 'IN/many' column(s)
3. One range test (`BETWEEN`, `<`, etc)

(A couple of side notes.)  The Optimizer is smart enough to clean up `WHERE 1 AND ...`.  But there are not many things that the Optimizer will handle.  In particular, this is not sargable:  `AND DATE(x) = '2020-02-20', but this does optimize as a "range":

```
    AND x >= '2020-02-20'
    AND x  < '2020-02-20' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

**Reading**

Building indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql
Sargable:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable
Tips on Many-to-many:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you use it.  In MySQL I found that `find_in_set` is way faster than using JSON when tested on the following commands, so much faster it wasn't even a competition (to be clear, the speed test did not include the `set` command line):

Fastest

```
set @ids = (select group_concat(`ID`) from `table`);
select count(*) from `table` where find_in_set(`ID`, @ids);
```

10 x slower

```
set @ids = (select json_arrayagg(`ID`) from `table`);
select count(*) from `table` where `ID` member of( @ids );
```

34 x slower

```
set @ids = (select json_arrayagg(`ID`) from `table`);
select count(*) from `table` where JSON_CONTAINS(@ids, convert(`ID`, char));
```

34 x slower

```
set @ids = (select json_arrayagg(`ID`) from `table`);
select count(*) from `table` where json_overlaps(@ids, json_array(`ID`));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name t1,(select 

group_concat('3698520147',',','088586004490',',','868332000057',',',
'081308003405',',','088394000028',',','089541300893',',','0732511000148',',','009191711092',

',','752830528161') as skuid)t

WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t1.sku,t.skuid)>0
```